# Assert function has been called once phpunit

Tags: phpunit

I'm new to PHPUnit and i'm wondering how to assert that a function from a service has been called.

I tried to mock my service that implement the function `ofDatetimeRange` :

```
$mock = $this->getMockBuilder(QueryBuilder::class)
            ->onlyMethods(['ofDatetimeRange'])
            ->getMock();
```

And then just call the function that suppose to call the service and finally assert that have been call once or never.

Here is the test case :

```
/**
     * Test that there is no date filter.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function testNoDateFilter()
    {
        $mock = $this->getMockBuilder(QueryBuilder::class)
            ->onlyMethods(['ofDatetimeRange'])
            ->getMock();

        $engine = new Engine();

        $engine->prepareQuery(); <--- this should call QueryBuilder::ofDatetimeRange
        $mock->expects($this->exactly(1))->method('ofDatetimeRange');
    }
```

> Expectation failed for method name is "ofDatetimeRange" when invoked 1
> time(s). Method was expected to be called 1 times, actually called 0
> times.

It looks like my engine doesn't use the mocked instance...

Is there something i'm doing wrong ?

Note that `$engine->prepareQuery()` should call `ofDatetimeRange` method of QueryBuilder class.

Answer (score 1):

You're right, $engine object in your test doesn't use the mock object.

I'm not sure how exactly Engine class looks like, but to be able to use mock you usualy should design your class to have mocked object dependency.

```
class Engine
{
    private QueryBuilder $qb;

    public function __construct(QueryBuilder $qb)
    {
        $this->qb = $qb;
    }
}
```

And then you pass the mock object in your test case:

```
$engine = new Engine($mock);
```

This should work.